# How to add content from url reading to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin

This is my code to read content from URL then add it into an arraylist. When I debug it shows that the sb.append(line) get the string but after that, the ArrayList data size = 0. So it's really confusing to me that the add sb doesn't work. How could i fix it?

```
var arrayListData = ArrayList<String>()
var config: Config = Config()

inner class GetData: AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): ArrayList<String> {
        val link = arrayOf(config.urlStatus, config.urlTongquan, config.urlBanggia)
        for (i in 0 until link.size){
            getContentURL(link[i])
        }
        return arrayListData
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: ArrayList<String>) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, result[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun getContentURL(url: String?) : ArrayList<String> {
    var sb = StringBuilder()
    val url = URL(url)
    val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    val inputStream: InputStream = urlConnection.inputStream
    val isr = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
    val br = BufferedReader(isr)

    var line: String? = ""
    try {
        do {
            line = br.readLine()
            if(line != null){
                sb.append(line)
                arrayListData.add(sb.toString())
            }
        }while (line != null)
        br.close()
    }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.d("AAA", e.toString())
    }
    return arrayListData
}
```

Comment: I think your objective is to get response of url right ? Why your are adding to arrayListData? . You can return sb.toString() at bottom to get content

Comment: As you see, I wanna take the data to result of onPostExecute() and use it with another function to process the data. Each URL, I use different fun. I think can't process one by one of my URLs in onPostExecute() by return sb.toString() at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to below one :

```
for (i in 0 until link.size){
                arrayListData.add(getContentURL(link[i]))
            }
```

Then return string from getContentURL() as given below :

```
private fun getContentURL(url: String?) : String {
    var sb = StringBuilder()
    val url = URL(url)
    val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    val inputStream: InputStream = urlConnection.inputStream
    val isr = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
    val br = BufferedReader(isr)

    var line: String? = ""
    try {
        do {
            line = br.readLine()
            if(line != null){
                sb.append(line)

            }
        }while (line != null)
        br.close()
    }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.d("AAA", e.toString())
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```